# Getting ".git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable" error while commit or push code to GIT branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Getting bellow error when I tried to commit or push code to my GIT Repo.

```
0 [main] sh 12996 fork: child 14076 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
.git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1238010 [main] sh 12996 fork: child 1392 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 1
1
.git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3479046 [main] sh 12996 fork: child 13076 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
11
.git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7730270 [main] sh 12996 fork: child 8168 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 1
1
.git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
15969580 [main] sh 12996 fork: child 6508 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
11
.git/hooks/pre-commit: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got this and rebooting my machine fixed it, so it's possible that I had "too many processes" but more likely I had a wifi/internet error.

Answer (score 0):

You open too many file or start too many processes. Try to figue out your system setting: open files and max user processes.